# No return type in Linq2SQL for stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, linq-to-sql

I have written a stored procedure in SQL and want to use it in my Linq2SQL designer. So I drag and drop it into my designer from server explorer in visual studio (2019) as I usually do, but this procedure has Return Type None.
Seems to be clear that there is no value returned when I look at my SQL procedure, because it use EXEC for executing a query, but I can see the result in SQL Server Management Studio.

Here is my stored procedure:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ret_VAL]

    @ITEMNR nvarchar(255), 
    @COLUM_NAME nvarchar(255)
    
AS
    DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(max)
    SET @query = N'SELECT ' + @COLUM_NAME + ' AS VALUE FROM [PROD].[dbo].[MMView] Where ITEMNUMBER like ''' + @ITEMNR + ''''
  EXEC (@query) 
GO
```

When I run the stored procedure in SSMS I am getting a result, but I can't use it in Linq2SQL. Sure, I can drag and drop it in my Linq2SQL designer but it has no Return Type. Can somebody tell me what I am missing here, to get a Return Type (Return value)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The L2S designer can't determine the return type for dynamically executed queries.

Are all columns that you pass in the "@colum_name" parameter of the same data type?

If so, if you temporarily change the stored proc to something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ret_VAL]

    @ITEMNR nvarchar(255), 
    @COLUM_NAME nvarchar(255)
    
AS
    SELECT top 1 somecolumn AS VALUE FROM [PROD].[dbo].[MMView] Where 1=0
GO
```

...and then add it to the L2S designer, then it should get the correct return type definition in the datacontext. Then you can change the stored proc back to the original definition.

However, if the columns are of different data type then that won't work since the definition will only match the column you use in the temporarily changed stored proc.

Comment: Oh, what a nice trick. :) This helps a lot. But as you said. There is one column which has another data type then the other columns have. This one is a decimal type, the others are of type char.
Therefore i am getting an casting exeption when i pass in the name for the column which has decimal as data type.

Comment: Yeah, if there are different data types then you need one SP definition for each type. ... or perhaps it's easier to skip the SP altogether and do it as a linq query directly against the table/view.

If the goal is to make it somewhat dynamic and choose column at runtime, then System.Linq.Dynamic may be an option:
https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library

Comment: I am going to ingnore this one column, as i do not need it. Thanks god, that there is only one column with a different type. :D
I am going to mark your answer as correct answer.

Comment: By the way, thank you for the very interesting link.

Comment: Thanks :) That link is a few years old, so there may be a newer version of System.Linq.Dynamic somewhere. However, that original one still works great so I'm still using it in a lot of places.